# Reading and displaying simple text from text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am fairly new to iphone development and programming in general and am wondering how to read some text from a text file to be diplayed in a UITextView. I have tried various ways to do it but just can't seem to be able to get it to display:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"txt"];

NSString *someText=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
textView.text=someText;
```

Some sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the file to your project using Menu -> Project -> Add to Project... or did you copy the file to your project folder from the Finder?

Comment: I created it in Xcode using File -> New File. But it's fixed now, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the name of the text file to 'untitled.txt' from just plain 'untitled' in Xcode. It *was* a text file but didn't have the extension of `.txt`. This doesn't seem to be automatically appended if you create the text file in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include the extension in the `pathForResource:` parameter:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"untitled.txt" ofType:@"txt"]`

should be

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"untitled" ofType:@"txt"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `untitled.txt` actually where you think it is? Try logging `filePath` and see if it's what you expect. (You could do `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:filePath]` to be completely certain.)

If the path is correct then the problem must be with loading the text. One such problem could be that the file is not encoded in UTF8. [Mike Ash recently blogged about character encoding](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-02-19-character-encodings.html). At the end of the post he describes how to handle text files of unknown encoding.

Comment: I had created untitled.txt just as a sample to see if this worked. I have checked and it is in UTF8. Putting in a few if statements, it seems that it is something to do with the file path. The file was created in Xcode in the resources folder.